# How to convert int to char[] with sprintf() if char is pointer and the int not?

Tags: c

I likely don't understand the `sprintf` function.

```
char s[30];
int i;

scanf("%d",&i);
sprintf(s,i); /*->warning: makes pointer from int*/
```

Comment: `sprintf(s, "%d", i);`

Comment: If you don't understand something, you can always read [its documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).

Comment: Thanks Johnny Mopp. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sprintf** accepts the target `char[]` as the first argument, and the rest of the arguments are the [same as `printf`, or `scanf`'s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (format string first, then additional args if present).

So, in your case, it would simply be:

```
char s[30];
int i;

scanf("%d",&i);
sprintf(s, "%d", i);
```

For an input of 3, `s` would become '3'.

With `sprintf(s, "%d%d", i, i);`, it would become '33'.

The reason it tried to interpret `i` as a pointer in your example, was that it *expected* a (char) pointer (the format string).